# For loop and scanf in a while loop

Tags: c

I have a small C program here that runs till you enter the `!` character. It works as expected when you enter the exclamation mark but when you enter any other character some additional hellos that I can't explain are output.

```
int main() {
    char in;
    while (in != '!') {
        printf("\nENTER:\n");
        scanf("%c", &in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("hello %c ", in);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop>gcc just.c && a.exe

ENTER:
a
hello a hello a hello a hello a hello a 
ENTER:
hello
 hello
 hello
 hello
 hello

ENTER:
!
hello ! hello ! hello ! hello ! hello !
```

Comment: Uninitialized local variables in C (like your `in` variable) really are *uninitialized*. They will have an *indeterminate* value (which you should look at as a "garbage" value). Don't use such variables in your code, always remember to initialize your variables.

Comment: As for your problem, the `%c` format doesn't skip leading white-space (which many other formats does). Like for example the newline that was left over from the last input. Change the format from `"%c"` to `" %c"` (note the leading space in the format string).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even after initializing the variable i am getting those extra hellos with "in" still having an indeterminate value.

Comment: While the solution might not have been intuitive (unless you read more about [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and its formats strings) a quick step-through in a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) should have made it clear that the newline from the previous input is read.

Comment: Yes, you entred an `'a'` and a newline. So two sets of 5 hellos. Notice the newline was output with the second set.

Comment: In addition to the comments from @Someprogrammerdude, when you access a variable with immediate storage duration (like your `in`) while its value is *indeterminate*, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* and all bets are off with your program. It can appear to run correctly or crash or anything in between.

Comment: I'll close this as one of the (thousands) of duplicates.

Comment: Notice how the "Related" questions don't even mention `scanf()`, much less anything about an uninitialized value (which would be impossible), but at least if the "Related" could pick up `scanf()` that would help with finding a duplicate. (good luck finding a good uninitialized variable dupe -- that's a needle in a haystack search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because `in` is uninitialized so the first test `in != '!'` may or may not be true and could eventually cause other side effects on mischievous systems.

The output you observe is consistent with the user typing the keys <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>!</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key produces a newline character `\n` in `stdin`, which is read by `scanf()` in the second iteration and output in the loop. The second and subsequent `hello` has a space before it because there is a space after `%c` in the `printf` format string.

You should use `scanf(" %c", &in);` to ignore whitespace and you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior at end of file.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char in = 0;
    while (in != '!') {
        printf("ENTER:\n");
        if (scanf(" %c", &in) != 1)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("hello %c ", in);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```